# pushing to remote private repo : fatal: repository not found

Tags: git, github

I successfully cloned remote private repo via

```
git clone https://github.com/notMyUsername/repoName
```

I recieved all the files from the repo - so there is no mistake in url

but when I am trying to push I get next errors:

```
$ git push --dry-run
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/notMyUsername/repoName/' not found

$ git push origin --dry-run
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/notMyUsername/repoName/' not found

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/notMyUsername/repoName (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/notMyUsername/repoName (push)
```

I also received notification from github for this repo, which tells that "You were automatically subscribed because you’ve been given push access to the repository." So I have rights.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does `git push origin --dry-run` work? What does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: @PerlDog, plz, see edited question

Comment: Yes, thx. Then I'd simply suggest it's a typo in the URL? Not sure what happens when you're not allowed to push into it. What does `git fetch origin` say? If it can connect, it should say "up-to-date" or sth. similar.

Comment: @PerlDog, not typo, I successfully cloned it, `git fetch origin -v` says "up to date" . So it looks like I have only read rights, but I recieved notification from github, that I have push access to the repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it fixed, and I did nothing(only wrote a message to the github support). And I saw some similar questions here on stackoverflow, where only time helped too.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have push rights on the GitHub repo, or you're not authenticated at all (but because you cloned, I assume you're authenticated).

As described by GitHub ( https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/ ), the GitHub API returns 404 for errors, not 403:

> **Why am I getting a 404 error on a repository that exists?**
>
> Typically, we send a 404 error when your client isn't properly
>   authenticated. You might expect to see a 403 Forbidden in these cases.
>   However, since we don't want to provide any information about private
>   repositories, the API returns a 404 error instead.
>
> To troubleshoot, ensure you're authenticating correctly, your OAuth
>   access token has the required scopes, and third-party application
>   restrictions are not blocking access.

You can only push to your own repositories on GitHub unless the repository owner has given you the right to push to that repository.

Comment: I have recieved email from github which tells me that "You were automatically subscribed because you’ve been given push access to the repository.". So let's assume that withs rights everything is ok, then what could be wrong with authentication if I can clone this repo, but can't push?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, was at home and sleeping. As you answered yourself, it works now - so it was a GitHub error. Regardless, it works now which is the important bit!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted github support and they told me to check my git credentials in Windows Credential Manager if I am using a windows machine. Seems that somehow the git credentials were incorrect. I corrected the credentials and push worked.
In a mac i guess the keychain would have the credentials.