# Pycharm, can't connect to a private repository

Tags: git, github, pycharm

My friend started a new (private) repository in Github and added me as a contributor.

I've successfully set up GitHub integration in Pycharm:

[image: Screenshot A]

However, when I'm trying to clone the repo, I'm getting a "repository not found" error.

[Screenshot B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7slF.png)

I've checked and I can see and make changes to the repo from the Github site.

Also, when the repo is changed from private to public, I can clone it, but can not push.

If anyone had run into this kind of problem before, I would be interested to know how they have solved it.

Thank you.

P.S:

I have tried to clone without testing.

I have tried to switch to SSH, and using Token or password authentication.

I have tried editing the link in /.git/config under `[remote "origin"]` to include my username like so:
`url = https://username@github.com/repoAuthorUsername/repo-name.git`
instead of the default:
`url = https://github.com/repoAuthorUsername/repo-name.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working with SSH by following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) guide from GitHub.

One needs to create a new SSH key from git bash (on windows)
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` where "your_email@example.com" is your GitHub mail.

Then one needs to add the SSH key to the ssh-agent:
`eval $(ssh-agent -s)` to start the agent. `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to add the key. (where id_rsa) is the key name.

After that, one needs to add the key to the GitHub account. In git bash `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to copy the key to clipboard and On any page in github go to settings-> ssh -> add ssh key and paste the key in.

When done, the git bash command `ssh -T git@github.com` should return:

> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

At this point cloning and pushing should work in pycharm (provided the setting "clone git repositories using ssh" is ticked in the settings menu)

**TL;DR**
All of the steps I've mentioned are described in greater detail and screenshots in this link https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add to this. Started a new company and constantly ran into this issue. When trying to pull/push to the remote I would get:

```
09:39:14.976: [convo-manager] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/blah/convo-manager.git/' not found
```

I finally found the answer in [JetBrains YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265570/Github-private-repository-of-organization-not-found#focus=Comments-27-5675423.0-0)

Basically in Git section of the JetBrains product turn on `Use credentials helper`. I imagine it's because when I authed with `gh` I used web oAuth flow.

[image]

Comment: Push to top as this is solved my issue in 2024, seems to be an issue if you push/pull from "Organization" github page.

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check the https url of that private repo: it is case sensitive.

Second, make sure:

- the owner has given you the right to push back to that repo (which should be the case as collaborator),
- you don't have existing credentials in the Windows credential Store.

See a similar case in "[pushing to remote private repo : fatal: repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35132582/6309)"

Comment: Thanks, I checked and I have rights to push. I've managed to get it working by creating an SSH key and linking it with github.